# Is it possible to take a Drupal site offline using Drush?

Tags: drupal, drush

Is it possible to take a Drupal site offline using Drush?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yep. `drush vset site_offline 1` will set it offline, then `drush vdel site_offline` will bring it back.

Alternatively, you can check out my [Maintenance File module](http://drupal.org/project/maintenance_file) on drupal.org, which will set your site to offline if it finds a specific file in the directory.

Answer (score 15):

Just in case anyone needs to do this with Drupal 7, the commands are:

```
drush vset maintenance_mode 1 --yes   # Take site offline 
drush vset maintenance_mode 0 --yes   # Put site back online
```

It also helps to add a little `drush cc all` after each of those commands to ensure that the change appears instantaneous to users.

Comment: This syntax also works with drupal 6 on current drush, so is probably preferred.

Answer (score 4):

theunraveler's solution is the best if you're running a single site.  We were running a very large multisite drupal installation, with hundreds of sites.  Taking them offline that way via drush takes several seconds per site which was unacceptable.  The fastest way to take a site offline is to break the db connection by for example renaming the settings.php file.  Then just assign a default theme that has a basic template that doesn't require the db, saying  "Site Offline" or something.  After upgrading you can just repair the settings.php file and you're good to go.

Comment: That takes just as long. To set a default theme for each site, you have to make a database change. The drush command above is also making a change in the database: it is the same as UPDATE {variables} SET value = 1 WHERE name = 'site_offline'. So, the issue is not with drush or even this method of setting sites offline, which is obviously the most ideal.

Comment: @theunraveler: I think the point is that you only need to make a single change once you have done the setup. Not a method I would use myself though.

Comment: @theunraveler: that's not the case.  in a multisite setup you can set a default theme in the base installation so that if you can't reach one of the "multisite" sites it defaults to that base theme.  trust me i spent a lot of time investigating this including making the db change directly.  that's not sufficient because the cache doesn't get flushed.  as i mentioned above, i don't recommend this unless you have a lot of sites and performance is important.  but with this technique you can take 500 sites offline in a couple seconds, versus 5-7 seconds per site via drush

Comment: Ah! I didn't know Drupal would fall back to a default theme if it couldn't find the actual theme. Although I still think that the Maintenance File module would be a better option. Good to know, though! +1

Answer (score 0):

With a site alias on D7:

```
drush @site_alias -y vset maintenance_mode 1    # Take site offline
drush @site_alias -y vset maintenance_mode 0    # Take site online
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy in fact, simply set the variable of maintenance mode to 1 (0 to restore default value):

```
drush vset maintenance_mode 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 6

```
drush vset site_offline 1
```

Drupal 7

```
drush vset maintenance_mode 1
```